# How can I speed up the FaceVerify process while using Azure FaceAPI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

So we're building a PHP application where a user needs to register a picture of their Face and when they login the application takes another picture of their face and compares it with the registered image using [MS Azure FaceAPI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/face/) and authenticates the user.

We're using AWS S3 to store all the images (about 12 KB each image) in the cloud. The authentication process takes over 6500 milli seconds (About 3500 ms to upload it to S3 and another 3000 ms to request the FaceAPI and receive a response)

Is there a way we can speed it up?

Comment: Beyond your network connection, the file size you pass in can have a significant impact on the performance. In many cases scaling down the images before sending is an approach worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenHeier.
We've already done it. The image size is less than 12KB and we're testing on a 50Mbps connection with over 10Mbps upload bandwidth. The performance was almost the same earlier when we were uploading images over 100KB over a 3G cellular network.

So our hypothesis is that there must some other performance bottleneck that we've been overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the region of your request API and the region of your S3. Is your API endpoint westUS, centralUS or other? Does it appear to be the same region with your storage and your request?